# Xcode 7.1 Simulators Constantly Freezing When I Use Them

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Recently (today and yesterday) my simulators have begun to freeze every single time I open them. I'll start my app up, and within a minute, even less, the entire simulator freezes and I get the spinning wheel of death. If I wait it will unfreeze and do the task, only to freeze again seconds later.

If I restart my computer it'll work for maybe 5 minutes before freezing, same if I reset the simulator. However, it always goes back to freezing on me. This is extremely frustrating, as you can imagine!

I've searched Google but haven't found anything mentioning my problem. Has anyone had this happen to them before? It only freezes after use, and it seems like the Settings app is the main cause of this, usually when I open the settings is when I run into issues.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Or what could possibly be going wrong with my simulators? I appreciate any help!

Comment: have you profiled your code for memory leaks

Comment: I haven't, but for the most part, once I can actually get the app running (takes forever, if it even works) it doesn't freeze much. It's while doing the setup and other operations that it freezes. Because testing my app means spending a lot of time outside the app on the springboard and in the settings bundle, this is a huge time waster when I have to constantly wait for it to unfreeze, never knowing if it will or not.

Comment: It freezes if you're trying to scroll the UIScrollView. I got the same. Super annoying and buggy.

Answer (score 21):

The "Window Snapping" feature in BetterTouchTool might cause this issue.

You could add the Simulator app in BTT, disable the scrolling & snapping feature for the simulator.

[Sample Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHLIU.png)

Comment: Having the same issue, this works. I disabled the snapping completely though, as I don't use it that much. Thank you. Interested in how did you find out these 2 are clashing.

Comment: Disabling BTT for the Simulator fixed this for me.

Comment: How did you add the simulator to BTT? Where is it located? Edit: Found it: https://www.codehive.io/boards/GNbBvUg

Comment: Wow, thank you! I had installed BTT about two months ago but didn't even think that it might be related to the simulator freezing. Now it's cleared right up.

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue with Simulator.app causing periodic SPODs for some use cases in Xcode 7.0 and 7.1.  The issue should be addressed in Xcode 7.2 beta.

If you see the issue in Xcode 7.2 beta or later, please take a sysdiagnose while the issue is reproducing, and file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openradar.me/23504761 recommends to try turn off apps that use accessibility features.

Turning off Flexiglass fixed it for me

Comment: BetterTouchTool was causing this issue for me. Quitting it solves the constant simulator freezing.

Comment: BetterSnapTool did it for me