# React Native development menu freezing in iOS emulator

Tags: ios, react-native

From yesterday I started getting this issue in iOS emulator:

When I hit cmd+D in iOS emulator to bring up development menu, App becomes unresponsive for ~30 sec. 
Then when I select something (Debug in chrome for example). Menu is gone, but app is unresponsive for another 30 sec or so.

This happens with apps that are just created:
`react-native init testapp`

In android emulator it works just fine.

Video sample (I am trying to click on menu item and then on count button every second or so): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7YIGeQK9lk

Code here: https://github.com/juozapas/reactsampleapp

`$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.19.0`

Comment: From @Andrush:

Thanks for the question, I've got the same issue since a couple of days! The issue is irrespective of emulator device type chosen and application run (I tested three different ones).

On a physical iOS device, the menu does not freeze!

It could perhaps be related to this ios Simulator freezing issue. But I'm not running BetterTouchTool and also don't know how to find out which apps of mine might use accessibility features.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at your video, it seems that you have enabled the **Slow animations** debugging mode in the iOS Simulator, perhaps by accidentally pressing `Cmd + T`.

Try turning off the slowed animations under the `Debug > Slow Animations`  menu or by pressing `Cmd + T` again.

I am not sure of the root cause of the unresponsiveness, but it is perhaps due to the native Action Sheet component animating out on the button press before the control is returned to the application.

Comment: Thanks, never thought that it can make animation sooo slow :)

Comment: @evakallio thanks for posting.  I never would have looked for a simulator setting to deliberately slow down animations.

Comment: HOLY, wasted half of the hour of my life on that, cool stuff!

Comment: this is a real life saver !!

Comment: My life saver! Great tip

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having trouble with emulators, you can at first use a physical iOS device to circumvent the issue. The react native menu does not freeze there (tested).

Periodical freezing of the screen can happen if you are using apps that use accessibility features, like e.g. BetterTouchTool or SizeUp with Xcode versions 7.0 and 7.1 and the issue should be resolved in Xcode 7.2 beta as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507202/xcode-7-1-simulators-constantly-freezing-when-i-use-them).

If that doesn't help, try disabling `Slow Animations` as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: I might have had an issue with Android emulator too, but I am not sure, it was late and I was just setting up android on my laptop.

But testing today, using Genymotion was all right

Comment: @jevakallio's answer solved it for me! I probably accidentally pressed `Cmd + T` while I tried to remember the shortcut to open the react native menu (which is `Cmd + ctrl + z` by the way ;-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11119004)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace That's exactly what I tried to do, but since I was not able to comment because I am still missing 9 reputation points, I explicitly wrote that into my post. I thought I still provide my thoughts since I had the same problem, but used a physical iOS device to circumvent the issue. I thought that sharing that might help the person asking since at that point the accepted answer which eventually helped me, too was not yet posted.

Comment: @Andrusch I understand. Still to keep things going smoothly around here stating it should be a comment and leaving it as an answer anyway isn't enough in my opinion. Here is what I suggest. Take the relevant information from your link and add it to your answer explaining what you did to resolve the issue. Also I gave you an up vote. Now you can comment anywhere. But please move the relevant information into the answer and remove the comment saying this should be a comment.

Comment: I have added the comment for you now you can remove this answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11119004)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Thanks for your upvote. I made changes to my answer as you suggested and am happy to now being able to comment where it is appropriate. I appreciate your help and drive for consistency on this site. I was very reluctant to post my thoughts as an answer at first, but eventually decided to do so for the reasons stated in the above comment.

Comment: @rptwsthi thanks for commenting for me. I now made changes to my answer as suggested by AtheistP3ace. Do you still want me to delete the post?